# Neural Network generates zeros as predictions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

I have the transactional data of 15 branches of a bank and I am trying to fit a neural network to it. Here is some background on the data.

- I have stored it in a dataframe which has date as index and transactions (debit) of each branch in a separate column, with its column name as **branch_id**.

- I used pandas interpolate method to fill the missing values with *filling method = time* i.e. `df.interpolate(method='time', axis=0, inplace=True)`

- Since the banking happens only during business days, therefore there was no data present for gazetted holidays and weekends. So, I filled zeros against those dates. `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`
- I have used the keras sequential model to create a neural network model. The code of which is given below

```
 from keras.models import Sequential
 from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout
 from keras.optimizers import Adam

 model = Sequential()
 model.add(BatchNormalization())
 model.add(Dense(32 , activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam())
 model.fit(X, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=31, verbose=0)
```

- Now when I fit the model on each branch data separately, the model fits very well on some branches while for rest it generates zeros when I generate predictions, even using the same training data.

Below is the code that I am using

```
def train_neural_network(actual_data, tbats_predictions, model, batch_size=31, epochs=100):

    X = predictions
    y = actual_data
    
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(32 , activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
    
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam())
    
    # Train the model in batches
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, batch_size=31, verbose=0)
    
    # Return the trained model
    return model


hybrid_forecast = {}

for col in df_dep.columns:
    act = np.array(train_data_deposit[col])
    act = act.reshape(-1, 1)

    preds = np.array(predictions[col])
    preds = preds.reshape(-1, 1)

    model = Sequential()
    model = train_neural_network(preds, act, model)

    forecast = model.predict(validation_data_deposit[col])

    hybrid_forecast[col] = forecast.squeeze()
```

I am not sure what is the reason for it. I have inspected the `training_data_dep` and `validation_data_deposit` for any missing values or NaNs but they are no present. Does it happen due to presence of zeros at weekends, if so then why does it work for some of the branches while fail for others?[[Model output for two branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4e3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nIai.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the activation on your last layer, from

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

Comment: Wouldn't changing the activation function to linear also produce negative results?

Comment: By changing the activation function to linear, my problem was solved but I don't understand why relu was causing issues and how does changing it to linear solves the problem. Please give me a little insight @Ioannis Nasios

Comment: relu activation function downclips values to 0. This prevents good training of a model for a regression task. Activation should always be linear on last layer for  regression, except there is some reason.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, relu function let's the model capture non-linear structure/pattern in the data and it only clips the negative part to zero. Also, should I use the linear activation in previous layers as well because the model is unable to learn anything from the data it only produces the same shape of the data as passed to it when predicting. Or is there something else that I should try to obtain a good fit?

Comment: you should use linear activation only in the output layer. Relu is a good activation function for the other layers.